# Batch - Escaping greater-than sign doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

In the following script i pass a qouted string to a subroutine and unquote it (with a tilde when accessing the parameter) to output it unquoted. Unfortunately my attempt to escape greater then sign(s) doesn't work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set foo="Argument -> Not provided^!"
    call :output_actual_error !foo!

    ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0

:output_actual_error
    SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set bar=%~1
    set bar=%bar:>=^>%
    echo %bar%
    ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

Output:

```
Argument - provided!
```

Expected:

```
Argument -> Not provided!
```

Please be aware that the code is just for illustration and DOES NOT represent the actual implementation.

So, how can escape the greater-than sign and `echo` the string without double?

Comment: The moment you strip the outer double quotes the `>` is exposed and interpreted as redirection. To avoid this enclose var and content together in a pair of double quotes `set "bar=%~1"` (that should be the normal use to avoid trailing spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
set "bar=%~1"
set "bar=%bar:>=^>%"
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution is already provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50778926). However, I want to show you how I would write the code to make it as safe as possible against all combinations of all kinds of special characters, by using proper quotation and enabling and applying delayed expansion only where it is really necessary and disabling it where it is disturbing or unsafe:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem /* No delayed expansion during immediate variable assignment,
rem    so escaping of exclamation marks is not required;
rem    quotation in a way not to become part of the value: */
set "foo=Argument -> Not provided!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Delayed expansion during reading of variable;
rem    quote argument value here to protect white-spaces: */
call :output_actual_error "!foo!"
endlocal
endlocal
exit /B 0


:output_actual_error
    rem /* No delayed expansion during argument expansion (%);
    rem    quotation in a way not to become part of the value: */
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "bar=%~1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Delayed expansion during reading of variable:
    echo(!bar!
    endlocal
    endlocal
    exit /B 0
```

This basically avoids delayed expansion during variable assignment and %-expansion and uses delayed expansion whenever a variable is read.

There still remain risks of failure:

1. One is introduced by `call`, because it doubles quoted carets (`^`).
2. Another one is represented by the argument expansion (`%~1`), which may cause trouble with quotes, particularly when they appear unbalanced.